# Weird cisco router activity

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, cisco, wifi

We have a Cisco 1811 router with one external ip. attached to that router is a Cisco wireless access point. We have a windows 2008 server attached to a switch port on the router.

No this is where it gets weird. From the windows server i can ping the access point but sometimes i can not ping the router. When i can ping the router it will work on a constant ping for about 3 minutes then it wont connect.

If i reboot the router the server can ping again.

When the windows server cant ping the network gets slow, and randomly disconnects. Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Is the IOS on the router current?

Answer (score 0):

First possible test would be to ensure the NIC is not set for "Autodetect" on the server. If the situation occurs over time, then you may want to try out the various line speed configurations and at the very least, run continuous ping tests from the server to the router in assessing each configuration's longterm stability.

Is this situation something new or has it existed since the deployment of the server/router?

Comment: This is something new.

Comment: Is the router accessible via its serial console when this occurs? If so, you might also look through its interface counters, router load, etc.